If/Elif Statement Only Responding to Initial Check
I'm still very new to Python and I'm coding a simple program to decrypt a poem. The first thing that needs to be done is that the user puts in the poem, which is broken down into a list, where then the base pairs are put into binary. To sort them into binary I've tried using an If/Elif statement (posted below) but the code routinely only responds to the first half. It will only print the 1's or 0's depending on which I leave first in the code.
basic = list(input("Enter the poem here!"))

trans = []
for n in basic:
    temp = basic.pop(0)
    print(temp)
    if (temp == 'T' or temp == 'G'):
        temp = 1
    elif (temp == 'A' or temp == 'C'):
        temp = 0
    trans.append(temp)


Can you give an example of input and expected output?
